# Google Follow Not Showing

Tags: html, css

Please help me solve this problem, Google Follow only shows the bubble but not the word "Follow", it seems like the width is automatically set to "0" when I check using Firebug.

Only shows the bubble:

[image]

Width=0:

[image]

Currently this is the CSS code that I use:

```
/*  header : social
/* ------------------------------------ */
.toggle-social { color: #fff; font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px; cursor: pointer;  padding: 13px 20px 13px 20px; display: block; position: absolute; right: 60px; top: -50px;
-webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);}
.toggle-social:hover,
.toggle-social.active { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15); color: #fff; }
.social-expand { display: none; background: #26272b; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 58px; width: 320px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1); }
.social-expand-inner { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15); font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px; padding: 13px 20px 13px 20px; display: block; position: relative;}
.follow-social {font-size: 1px;}
/* This gets Facebook to fall into place */
.follow-social iframe { vertical-align: middle; }
/* Set an optional width for your button wrappers */
.follow-social span { display: inline-block; width: 90px; }
/* Adjust the widths individually if you like */
.follow-social .followgoogle { width: 75px; }
```

This is the Google Follow button:
developers.google.com/+/web/follow/

I tried to view it using Google Chrome, it render correctly:
http://s11.postimg.org/i1wh1nudf/work_on_chrome.png
When using Firefox, the problem still exists.

Comment: Do you use Adblock? If yes, can you turn it off and try again.

Comment: No, I don't use Adblock. On Google site, it says that "The width of the button is automatically calculated to fit the label in the user's language." I already chosen English, but the width still 0.

Comment: is there any demo link or fiddle..?

Comment: Currently the site is on localhost. Sorry, I don't know how to make it work on jsfiddle(dot)net

Comment: It works on Google Chrome, but on Firefox, the problem still exists. Please someone give suggestion.